# Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: c#, wcf, odbc, database-connection

I am getting this error anytime I try to open my ODBC connection.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="ODBCConnection"
     connectionString="Driver={IBM InfoSphere Classic ODBC Driver V10.1};Server=xxx.xxxxxx.COM,6666;Database=DTM;"
     providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
```

I am not using a DSN as I didn't think it was necessary and that the connection string could handle all that. Can someone tell me what is wrong with that connection string?

Edit: Updated connection string that still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"IBM InfoSpere Class ODBC Driver V10.1" has to be the exact driver string you will find in the ODBC Administrator. Note if you are on a 64 bit windows machine there are 2 ODBC Administrators, one for 32 bit and for 64 bit. See [64-bit ODBC](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html) which explains where to find each one. You need to know whether your application is 32 or 64 bit and match that to the administrator.

Comment: I got that string from the odbc admin. I am on 64 bit win 7. Though since I am launching my wcf app via Visual Studio, I guess it would be a 32 bit app since VS is a 32 bit app.

Comment: Installed the 32 bit version and it gets past this. Though now it has an issue with the connection string syntax.

Comment: I'd definitely use uppercase for the DRIVER attribute.

Comment: Edited my initial post with updated connection string that still doesn't work.